# Mongo C++ bulk operations

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

How do I execute bulk operations with the new Mongocxx driver? The driver manual is horrible. And there are no examples anywhere!!!

Relevant class: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-3.1.1/classmongocxx_1_1bulk__write.html

I can create an operation using `bulk_write::bulk_write()` and add queries using `bulk_write::append()`. But I am confused as to how to execute it.

It's terrible that they don't provide similar functions like the mongo shell.
Ex: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/

Comment: There is an entire directory of example code here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/tree/releases/stable/examples, including one for bulk writes.

Comment: Whoa!! Thanks a lot! Wish I had seen that before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **bulk_write** instance, then populate it with write operations and finally submit it to Mongo collection using this method:

```
collection::bulk_write(const bulk_write& bulk_write)
```

Comment: That answer is wrong. see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/releases/stable/examples/mongocxx/bulk_write.cpp

Comment: It was correct (my code similar to this answer used to compile with older versions of mongocxx but the interface was changed). It is not correct for mongocxx 3.4.